# In a cloned github repo, I can cd into a branch(folder) but not git checkout, why is this?

Tags: git, github

This is the repo https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms.git

I have never come across something like before.

Comment: How do you `cd`  on GitHub? I don't see any branches in the linked repository.

Comment: It a repo has only a master branch, but many folders, do you just cd into those folders?

Comment: Sure, that's what folders are for.

Answer (score 2):

There is only a single branch in the repository you mentioned ("master").  A clone of this repository will pull down the master branch to your local repository.  `git checkout` is used to checkout an existing branch.  If you need to create a branch, you can do so by running `git branch NEW_BRANCH` but then you'll need to check it out to use it.  `git checkout -b NEW_BRANCH` would both create a new branch called "NEW_BRANCH" based on the current branch and check it out.  Using `cd` to move in and out of folders is a terminal command for directory traversal and has nothing to do with git.  The web is full of git tutorials.  I'd suggest taking a few of them to clarify these points.

Answer (score 0):

The question (and its title) suggest that you may be thinking that folders and branches are the same thing.  In some tools (like TFVC) that may be more or less true, but in git they are unrelated things.

A branch is a pointer to a commit.  There is a hierarchy of branch names (and other refs), but it's unrelated to the folder structure[1].

Each commit has a `TREE` that represents the project content at a particular time.  The commit's `TREE` is the root of a hierarchy of `TREE` and `BLOB` objects, which parallels the directory/file layout of the project (and therefore of the work tree when checked out).

Using `git worktree`, you could lay out a local workspace that maps branches to directories in a manner similar to a tool like TFVC if you wanted; but it isn't the default/natural way in git.

---

[1] Well, ok, to nitpick: one way that git can represent the ref hierarchy within its metadata involves a folder/file hierarchy under `.git/`, but that's not always the case, and it's not something you'd typically see or interact with anyway.  That is, it's still unrelated to the folder structure of the *content*.

Comment: What I was intending to ask was that the repo I cloned has only a master branch made up of many folders. I made the mistake of typing git checkout ( name of folder). However when I typed cd (folder name) it worked.

Comment: @Pazira But still, branches are a way of organising commits whereas folders are a way of organising files. In Git, they are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

For the repo you linked. calling `git checkout <Anything>` is not going to successfully do anything unless you created another branch with 
`git checkout -b <branch>` or
`git branch <branch>`

Mark Adelsberger explained well how branches aren't the same as folders, but I would like to add that git checkout branches moves between versions of code, whereas cd  changes your location in the code.